# Memory leak or access violation using Delphi TJSONObject and TJSONArray

Tags: json, delphi

I have a simple function in a Delphi Windows app that is chasing me in circles.

If I run it as follows, I get a memory leak:

```pascal
function TtrackingsingleDlog.getJsonValue (const isScanDataB:boolean; scanNumberI: integer; pairnameS,fullStringS: string):string;
var
  jobject: TJSONObject;
  jobject2: TJSONObject;
  scansarray: TJSONArray;
  valueStringS:string;
begin
  valueStringS:='';
  jobject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(fullStringS) as TJSONObject;
  if isScanDataB then
  begin
    jobject.TryGetValue('data', jobject2);
    if scanNumberI>=0 then
    begin
      if jobject2.TryGetValue('scans', scansarray) then
      begin
        scansarray[scanNumberI].TryGetValue<string>(pairnameS,valueStringS);
        jobject2.free;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      jobject2.TryGetValue(pairnameS, valueStringS);
      jobject2.free;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    jobject.TryGetValue(pairnameS, valueStringS);
    jobject.free;
  end;
  result:=valueStringS;
end;
```

If I comment out the `if scanNumberI>=0` section, and free the `jobject`, as follows, the leak goes away:

```pascal
function TtrackingsingleDlog.getJsonValue (const isScanDataB:boolean; scanNumberI: integer; pairnameS,fullStringS: string):string;
var
  jobject: TJSONObject;
  jobject2: TJSONObject;
  scansarray: TJSONArray;
  valueStringS:string;
begin
  valueStringS:='';
  jobject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(fullStringS) as TJSONObject;
  if isScanDataB then
  begin
    jobject.TryGetValue('data', jobject2);
    {if scanNumberI>=0 then
    begin
      if jobject2.TryGetValue('scans', scansarray) then
      begin
        scansarray[scanNumberI].TryGetValue<string>(pairnameS,valueStringS);
        jobject2.free;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      jobject2.TryGetValue(pairnameS, valueStringS);
      jobject2.free;
    end; }
    jobject.free;
  end
  else
  begin
    jobject.TryGetValue(pairnameS, valueStringS);
    jobject.free;
  end;
  result:=valueStringS;
end;
```

But, if I put that section back in, the `jobject.free` throws an Access Violation.

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, but just can't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you have shown, the *only* object you are responsible for freeing is the one that is returned by `ParseJSONValue()` (and you should be protecting that with a `try..finally`!).

DO NOT try to free any of the inner objects you extract from the JSON, as they are owned by the top-level JSON object by default and so will be freed for you automatically when you free the top object.

If you want to take ownership of the inner objects, you have to manually set their `Owned` property to `False`.

Try this:

```
function TtrackingsingleDlog.getJsonValue (const isScanDataB: boolean; scanNumberI: integer; pairnameS, fullStringS: string): string;
var
  jvalue: TJSONValue;
  jobject: TJSONObject;
  jobject2: TJSONObject;
  scansarray: TJSONArray;
  valueStringS: string;
begin
  valueStringS := '';
  jvalue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(fullStringS);
  if jvalue <> nil then
  try
    jobject := jvalue as TJSONObject;
    if isScanDataB then
    begin
      if jobject.TryGetValue('data', jobject2) then
      begin
        if scanNumberI >= 0 then
        begin
          if jobject2.TryGetValue('scans', scansarray) then
          begin
            scansarray[scanNumberI].TryGetValue<string>(pairnameS, valueStringS);
          end;
        end
        else
        begin
          jobject2.TryGetValue(pairnameS, valueStringS);
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      jobject.TryGetValue(pairnameS, valueStringS);
    end;
  finally
    jvalue.Free;
  end;
  Result := valueStringS;
end;
```

Comment: Remy,Thank you so much.  You've been a lifeline for many developers, including me, for years and we appreciate it.